# Transit visa for Australia

Tags: visas, transit, australia, transit-visas

I have questions regarding transiting through Australia, will be flying from Port Moresby to Brisbane, scheduled to arrive at 9.25 am. Our connecting flight from Brisbane to Fiji is scheduled to depart Brisbane at 11.30 am.

Do we have to apply for a transit visa for Australia? We will be in Brisbane airport for an hour and a half before boarding our next flight.

Comment: What is FJ?  Airport codes are three letters.

Comment: Guessing it's the country Fiji, not an airport...

Comment: Unless it refers to FJ, the prefix of all ICAO airport codes in British Indian Ocean Territory (eg FJDG - Diego Garcia)

Comment: Also sue - what's your citizenship? Very important when it comes to visas.

Answer (score 3):

You need to visit the [Do I need a Transit Visa](http://www.immi.gov.au/faqs/Pages/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-through-australia.aspx) page. Check whether your passport makes you to be in the "Categories of eligible travellers". The Criteria you seem to have fulfilled:

- enter Australia by Aircraft
- leave within 8 hours,
- not need to leave the airport transit lounge except to continue their journey -- with this timeframe, I will presume you have a single ticket and as such, your luggage will be checked through to Fiji so you don't need to pick up your luggage and check in again.
- and I can only presume you have the necessary paperwork to enter Fiji.